# Notifications aren't receiving to iPhone using swift from firebase cloud messaging

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I want to send the notifications from my application to another application using firebase cloud messaging. So I used this method retrieveFCMToken(forSenderID: senderid) for that process. I add the piece of code to my app delegate that is :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    let senderid = "<YOUR SENDER ID>"
    Messaging.messaging().retrieveFCMToken(forSenderID: senderid) {(message,Error) in  
        print("message",message!)
    }
}
```

and this is my app delegate :

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]
        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

        //Code for sending to other sender ID
        let senderid = "xxxxxxxx"
        Messaging.messaging().retrieveFCMToken(forSenderID: senderid) {(message,Error) in  // here i am generating the token for other sender id project
            print("message",message!)
        }
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

I followed this scenario : I have two apps that is "A" and "B". I want to send the notifications from an app "A" to app "B". So I placed the sender id of the app A into the app B delegate file and generated the registration token for app A using app B. So I placed the generated registration token in firebase cloud messaging console of app A while sending the notification to app B. But the app B is not getting the notifications. How to solve this error? I uploaded the valid APN's Auth key in both apps database in firebase cloud messaging.

Comment: Are both Apps under same Firebase Project or different projects?

Comment: @SahilManchanda pointed out right. Are the both apps under the same firebase project or not?

Comment: @SahilManchanda,@Sivajee Battina Bothe apps using different databases.

Answer (score 0):

A & B are two SEPARATE APPS, therefore, one's FCM token is not valid for the other one. Each App generates Unique Token that is relevant to its Firebase Project only. In order to send and receive notifications from A To B or B To A, you need to configure both Firebase projects in each App and then retrieve the corresponding FCM token. After that, you would be able to send and receive Notifications

Comment: what is mean by configure projects?

Comment: it means adding other instance of FirebaseApp in both iOS project. btw do you have a backend server it could be solved easily with a backend server

Answer (score 0):

The method of extension you have written is okay. But please check the below things from FCM console to find the issue of not receiving Notification.

For another app which you are referring you must need to add bundle id of that to FCM and the need to generate google info.plist file for that particular app. Then you have to follow the steps to check Notification in your app.

Things to check for FCM token in iOS

1. Please check that in console.firebase.com your app has proper p.12 file in application setting.
2. Server has set proper server api key which is shown in console.firebase.com application setting.
3. Google info.plist file must be download and add to project.

Hope this help to you.

Comment: I uploaded the APN's auth key not p12 certificate. All the things are set correctly

Comment: @LahariAreti Yeah right that's the auth key. If both the auth keys for both app are correct then please check that whether it's set correctly from side menu "Cloud Messaging". Send notification check notification to your app from there. If come it mean you have set it correctly then you just need to give the "Server key to backend"

Comment: Yea the APN's auth key is set correctly . I am getting notifications from same app.

Comment: @LahariAreti If you are getting notification there then there is no mistake in firebase side. Then please check in xcode as your code is okay, capabilities in build. Have you enable capability - > push notification.

IF SATISFIED THEN PLEASE VOTE FOR ME.